# PHPStorm и live edit для php файлов выбивают ошибку 502

Tags: php, phpstorm

Здравствуйте
Использую PHPStorm и live edit плагин для верстки, верстка в файлах php что бы цеплять одинаковы секции (header, footer и т.д). 
Когда редактирую css и html все прекрасно работает, но когда начинаю редактировать php файл, страница уходит на перезагрузку и часто выбивает после этого ошибку `502 Bad Gateway`, и обратно включается только после `5 - ∞`  перезагрузка браузера, иногда приходится перезаходить в редактор. PHP подключен от XAMP.
Спасибо за уделенное время!

Comment: Какая у вас версия PHPStorm, на каком сервере запущено приложение?

Comment: @lena Здравствуйте! версия 2017.1, сервер от xampp

Comment: хмм... в случае php Live Edit просто сохраняет файл автоматически в процессе изменения. и перегружает страницу в браузере. Возможно, XAMP не всегда корректно обрабатывает такую перезагрузку... у нас были проблемы со встроенным вебсервером (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317), но в случае XAMP не знаю, что это может быть:(

Comment: @lena я настроил интерпретатор php но не уверен что он через него запускает( Указывал в настройках проекта пункт к нему, но в любом случае я запускаю дебаг JS а не php

Comment: а что за url у вас в run конфигурации?

Comment: @lena http://localhost:63342/gulp/app/catalog.php
Изменил на http://localhost/gulp/app/catalog.php спасибо что навели на мысль)  по идеи так он должен через xampp запускаться. Большое спасибо) Если нужен отзыв (или как он тут называется:) Напишите ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, это проблема встроенного вебсервера (`localhost:63342`); похоже на [WEB-17317](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317). Попробуйте запустить Ваше приложение на другом вебсервере (XAMP?)

Comment: Вылез еще один баг) теперь live edit не работает для css стилей, а только php файл нормально работает(

Comment: пожалуйста, создайте support ticket

Comment: спасибо еще раз)